# Prolog - increment value of list

Tags: prolog, counter, increment

I'm new with Prolog and have some difficulties concerning basically a counter.

This code works :

```
listProf(L1) :-
   findall((LastName,FirstName,Id), professor(Id,LastName,FirstName), L1).
```

`L1` is a list and is under the following form : `L1(LastName,FirstName, Id)`

So now i have a list `L1`. I need to create a new list after this one, that is under the form : 
`L2(LastName, FistName, NumberOfCredits)`

NumberOfCredits should be incremented by 3 if the Id in L1 match the id in : 
`groupeCours( _, _, _, _,Id,( _, _))`.

I thought of this but obviously doesn't work :

```
profNbcredits(L) :-
   findall((LastName,FirstName,NbCredits),
      (  listProf([(_,_,Id)]),
         groupeCours( _, _, _, _,Id,( _, _)),
         NbCredits is NbCredits +3
      ),
      L).
```

I know that "NbCredits is NbCredits +3" doesnt work in logic programming and that i need two "variables" but i can't manage to find a way.
Also, i'm not sure of : listProf([(*,*,Id)]). With this i'm trying to get the Id of each triplets in the list listProf.

Do you have any ideas?

A bit of the "database" :

```
groupeCours('INF1110', 20, 32003, 100, 'TREJ4',('Thursday',1)).
groupeCours('INF1110', 30, 32003, 100, 'PASB1',('Wednesday',2)).
groupeCours('INF1130', 10, 32003, 100, 'PASB1',('Monday',2)).

professor('TREJ4', 'Tremblay', 'Jean').
professor('DEVL2', 'De Vinci', 'Leonard').
professor('PASB1', 'Pascal', 'Blaise').
professor('GOLA1', 'Goldberg', 'Adele').
```

Comment: A list of the form `L1(LastName,FirstName, Id)` doesn't make sense. Do you mean a list `L1` whose elements are of the form `(LastName,FirstName, Id)`?

Comment: When you say, *`NumberOfCredits` should be incremented by 3 if the `Id` in `L1` match*, but where does the original value of `NumberOfCredits` that you want to increment come from

Comment: Yes i mean a list L1 whose elements are (LastName,FirstName, Id). And for NumberOfCredits, it's supposed to be 0 at the beginning of the scan of the list

Comment: Can you give what you expect to see with the "bit of database" you show? It is maybe easier to understand? Or maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `listProf/1` to accomplish your task. Also, nowhere do you start with a `0` credit count (`0` doesn't appear anywhere in your code).

Although you're question never came right out and said what you're trying to do and what the assumptions are, it looks like you're ultimately trying to determine total credits offered per professor, and that the assumption is simply that each course is fixed at 3 credits. I would have expected a database of courses which indicates how many credits apply, but that doesn't seem to be what you have.

It would probably make more sense, then to start with a predicate that provides total credits for a given professor Id:

```
professor_total_credits(ProfId, TotalCredits) :-
    findall(3, groupeCours(_, _, _, _, ProfId, _), Credits),
    sum_list(Credits, TotalCredits).
```

Then you can list all of them:

```
professors_total_credits(ProfTotalCredits) :-
    findall((ProfLast, ProfFirst, Credits),
            (professor(Id, ProfLast, ProfFirst),
             professor_total_credits(Id, Credits)),
            ProfTotalCredits).
```